# How many solutions does this equation has in a finite field

Tags: field-theory

I'm working in a finite field $F_q$ where q is a primepower. As a small part of a problem I'm working on, I have to find how many solutions the equation $x^2-ay^2-1=0$ has in $F_q$, with $a \in F_q\backslash\{0\}$. Trying in $F_5=Z_5$ I found the answer depends on a but I can't find the general answer (if x or y wouldn't have been squared it would be easy!).

Thanx in advance!

Comment: It all depends on whether $a$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_q$ or not. When $q=p$ is a prime you seem to get $p-1$ solutions when $a$ is a square and $p+1$ solutions when $a$ isn't.

Answer (score 1):

In the prime case, you can consider $${1\over p}\sum_{t=0}^{p-1}\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\sum_{y=0}^{p-1}e^{2\pi i(x^2-ay^2-1)t/p}$$ If $x^2-ay^2-1\equiv0\pmod p$, then the sum on $t$ gives $p$; otherwise, zero; so the sum exactly counts the number of solutions. Pulling out the terms with $t=0$, you can rewrite as $$p+{1\over p}\sum_{t=1}^{p-1}e^{-2\pi it/p}\sum_xe^{2\pi itx^2/p}\sum_ye^{-2\pi iaty^2/p}$$ and the inner sums are Gauss sums which have well-known evaluations (just search for "Gauss sums").